# how can I get nested Scope properties with a get()

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have the following problem: I need to get Scope properties with `.get(myparameter)`, to call it in a function.

```
var myobj = new Object();
myobj.vname = "firstname"
myobj.lname = "lastname"
sessionScope.Me = myobj;
print (sessionScope.Me.vname)
print (sessionScope.Me.get("vname"))
```

The first print is okay, but the second throws this error:

> Error calling method 'get(string)' on an object of type 'Object [JavaScript Object]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Javascript, use an indexer.

```
print (sessionScope.Me["vname"])
```

There is no `get` function on your `Me` object.